# Convert table() to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have this dummy data:

```
x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
y = c("h", "i", "j", "h", "j")
input_data = data.frame(cbind(x, y))
input_data

  x y
1 a h
2 a i
3 a j
4 b h
5 b j
```

I would like to convert the following to a dataframe:

```
table(input_data$x, input_data$y)

    h i j
  a 1 1 1
  b 1 0 1
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work (I want the exact layout of table(*) output above). Any solutions? Thanks.

```
as.data.frame(table(input_data$x, input_data$y))

  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a    h    1
2    b    h    1
3    a    i    1
4    b    i    0
5    a    j    1
6    b    j    1
```

Comment: `xtabs(~ ., input_data)`